# How to set mapping to colors in seaborn.heatmap?

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap, correlation

I'm trying to plot a correlation matrix with sns.heatmap(). Specifically, the code I run is

```
corr = train.corr()
sns.heatmap(corr, cmap = "RdBu_r")
```

This returns following image:
[image: correlation matrix]

What I want is to 0 to correspond to white, positive correlations to be in shades of red and negative to be in shades of blue. I went through the documentation of seaborn, however, I wasn't able to figure it out.

Is there a way how to set this in seaborn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try playing with `vmin` and `vmax` attribute, as mentioned [here](https://python-graph-gallery.com/92-control-color-in-seaborn-heatmaps/)

Answer (score 3):

A more robust solution might be to use the `center` argument in `heatmap` to set the center for plotting divergent data.

```
A = np.random.normal(1, 3, [5,5])
sns.heatmap(A, center=0, cmap=sns.diverging_palette(220, 20, as_cmap=True))
```

Results in
[the following figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLI1J.png)